# RGB to gray conversion of all image in a folder, save them to other folder with original names

Tags: matlab, converters, octave, rgb, grayscale

I have this code which converts image to gray and saves it in the current folder:

```
directory = dir('AM01AFS.jpg');
for i = 1 : size(directory,1)
   filename = directory(i).name;
   img = rgb2gray(imread(filename));
   imwrite(img, ['Gr_' filename]);
end
```

I need to convert a folder (images) from RGB to gray and save them in `Output` folder with the same original names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine.
I hope you need to convert RGB to Gary, and not GRB to Gary...

1. Modify `directory = dir('AM01AFS.jpg');` to `directory = dir('*.jpg');`
2. Create new output directory, if you don't wont to override existing images.

   ```
   %Assume jpg images are in the same directory as the m file.
   indir = cd; %Modify the indir to location of the jpg files.
   outdir = 'Gray'; %Name or output directory.
   directory = dir([indir, '\', '*.jpg']);

   if ((~exist(outdir, 'dir') && length(directory) > 0))
       %Create new directory named outdir if directory not exist.
       mkdir(outdir);
   end

   for i = 1 : length(directory)
       filename = directory(i).name;
       rgb_img = imread([indir, '\', filename]);    
       if (ndims(rgb_img) == 3) %Make sure img is RGB (not gray).
           img = rgb2gray(rgb_img);
           %Save gray image to outdir (keep original name).
           imwrite(img, [outdir, '\', filename]);
       end
   end
   ```

---

If you like to open folder selection dialog box, you can use the following example:

```
%Open folder selection dialog box, for selecting input and output folders.
indir = uigetdir(cd, 'Select input folder');
outdir = uigetdir(cd, 'Select output folder');
directory = dir([indir, '\', '*.jpg']);

for i = 1 : length(directory)
    filename = directory(i).name;
    rgb_img = imread([indir, '\', filename]);    
    if (ndims(rgb_img) == 3) %Make sure img is RGB (not gray).
        img = rgb2gray(rgb_img);
        %Save gray image to outdir (keep original name).
        imwrite(img, [outdir, '\', filename]);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Rotem, But Where i can put input directory folder?

Comment: You are right, I assumed jpg images are in the same directory as the Matlab m file. (I modified the code to include `indir`). I also corrected a small bug.

Comment: Thanks @Rotem, This is exactly what i really need.

Comment: You should use `fullfile` to create a filename which uses / on Unixes and \ in windoze

Comment: I think Windows accepts both / and \, I am using \ out of bad habits.